# why print(x) from class although I have not made an instance of the class?

Tags: python, oop

```
x = 5


class A:
    x += 1  # here we can access and change the value of x in class but only for class
    print(f"x from inside class is {x}")


print(x)
```

why print inside the class although i not make instance  from the class A

Comment: Because everything in the class definition is executed at runtime. Nothing in the class block is actually executed when you create an instance, although, functions defined there will be called (e.g. `__init__`)

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga i think you hit it :)  without more discuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python code is [executed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) top to bottom. The statement `class A` triggers the creation of a new class object, which will be finalized and assigned to the global name `A` when the unindent is reached.

A [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is [created](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) by running all the statements in the class body in a separate isolated [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). Once the class body finishes [executing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#executing-the-class-body), the namespace is wrapped up into a class [object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object). The result can be pre-processed by a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses), but that's about it.

The statement `x += 1` is roughly equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(1)`. The [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) happens inside the class namespace. It does not affect the global name `x` because assignments happen in the class namespace and integers are immutable. The immutability is important, because the `x` on the right hand side of that assignment is from the global namespace, even if the left one is not.

A mutable object like a list would work differently. If `x` was a list, `x += [1]` would reassign the result of `x.__iadd__([1])` to a class variable `x`, just as for the integer case. However, the operation [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.iadd) modifies a list object in-place. That means that both global `x` and `A.x` would refer to the same expanded list.

A [`class`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) statement, like a [`def`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) statement is an assignment operation. You are telling the interpreter to run a code snippet that initializes your class. This is different from `def`, which does *not* run any lines of code that you wrote, instead compiling them into a function object.

You see the printout happen as the interpreter creates the class namespace. The class ends up with a variable called `x` set to `6`. If you had `def` statements, there would also be functions in the class namespace. If you attempted to [access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) those functions through an instance of the class, they would get bound as methods since function objects are non-data [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. You're right. I just checked that too. I just took out that sentence, since it's really not all that relevant.

Comment: @MadPhysicist   can you tell me any big reference to read about this topic

Comment: @ahmed_flux. I am in the process of linking all the main concepts I mention to the official documentation. It's quite good, and not a bad read at all. In fact, I generally find most of it easier to read than some "tutorial" material because it is precise and unambiguous.

Comment: @ahmed_flux. This link, and really everything on that page will teach you pretty much everything you need to know about how python works: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Comment: @ahmed_flux. I've added the links. All of them are to the official docs, as promised.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` initialized outside is pointing to different object address from that of variable `x` inside the class. It creates a new static variable for class A with the value of outside `x+1`. To see this, I am printing the address pointed by variables here. See that the addresses pointed by variable `x` are different outside and inside the class.

```
x= 5
print('address of x just after outside initialization',id(x))

class A:
    x += 1  # here we can access and change the value of x in class but only for class
    print(f"x from inside class is {x}")
    print('address of x from inside class is', id(x))


print('value outside class',x)
print('address of x just after execution',id(x))
```

Output:

```
address of x just after outside initialization 94841399200384
x from inside class is 6
address of x from inside class is 94841399200416
5
address of x just after execution 94841399200384
```

Comment: Variables don't have addresses, objects do. The address is a red herring. Even if you use, say, `x = []` and in the class definition statement, `x += [1]`, they will have the *same id* because two *different variables* will refer to the *same object*.

Comment: The `id` is *irrelevant*.  I don't know what you are trying to demonstrate with that comment. Again, **the id doesn't matter**. What matters is that there are **two different variables**. They can be referring to the same object or different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a static variable x, one that is not tied to any instance of A and is created immediately. To create an instance variable, do this:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent to yours.

```
x = 5


class A:
    x = x + 1
    print(f"x from inside class is {x}")


print(x)
print(A.x)
```

And it outputs:

```
x from inside class is 6
5
6
```

So as you can see, what you have done with `x += 1` is define a class variable `A.x` that has the value of `x + 1`. This `x` is pulled from the outer scope (value = 5). So you actually have 2 variables at play here, not one like you are assuming.

Comment: first thank you for reply 
second you mean that x in class is equal to A.x (inside the class ) so class  call it self or some thing like that

Comment: No. The class body is run when you define the class. And as part of that, when you do `x += 1`, that defines `A.x` and the value of  `A.x` (i.e. `x + 1`) uses the `x` from outside the class.